# Node: How can I use pipe and change one file from a multipart

Tags: node.js, http, stream, pipe, multipart

I have a http service that needs to redirect a request, I am not using streams because I deal with big files in multipart and it overwhelms RAM or disk(see [How do Node.js Streams work?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28356033/1577343))

Now I am using pipes and it works, the code is something of this sort:

```
var Req = getReq(response);
request.pipe(Req);
```

The only shortcoming of this is that in this multipart I resend in the pipe contains one JSON file that needs a few fields to be changed.

Can I still use a pipe and change one file in the piped multipart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a [Transform Stream](https://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_duplex_and_transform_streams).

```
var Req = getReq(response);
var transformStream = new TransformStream();

// the boundary key for the multipart is in the headers['content-type']
// if this isn't set, the multipart request would be invalid
Req.headers['content-type'] = request.headers['content-type'];

// pipe from request to our transform stream, and then to Req
// it will pipe chunks, so it won't use too much RAM
// however, you will have to keep the JSON you want to modify in memory
request.pipe(transformStream).pipe(Req);
```

Transform Stream code:

```
var Transform = require('stream').Transform,
    util = require('util');

var TransformStream = function() {
  Transform.call(this, {objectMode: true});
};
util.inherits(TransformStream, Transform);

TransformStream.prototype._transform = function(chunk, encoding, callback) {

// here should be the "modify" logic;

// this will push all chunks as they come, leaving the multipart unchanged
// there's no limitation on what you can push
// you can push nothing, or you can push an entire file
  this.push(chunk);
  callback();
};

TransformStream.prototype._flush = function (callback) {
    // you can push in _flush
    // this.push( SOMETHING );      
    callback();
};
```

In the _transform function, your logic should be something like this:

1. If, in the current chunk, the JSON you want to modify begins

   `<SOME_DATA_BEFORE_JSON> <MY_JSON_START>`

   then `this.push(SOME_DATA_BEFORE_JSON);` and keep `MY_JSON_START` in a local var
2. While your JSON hasn't ended, append the chunk to your local var
3. If, in the current chunk, the JSON ends:

   `<JSON_END> <SOME_DATA_AFTER_JSON>`

   then add `JSON_END` to your var, do whatever changes you want,
   and push the changes: 
   `this.push(local_var);`
   `this.push(SOME_DATA_AFTER_JSON);`
4. If current chunk has nothing of your JSON, simply push the chunk

   `this.push(chunk);`

Other than that, you may want to read the [multipart format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Multipart_messages).
`SOME_DATA_BEFORE_JSON` from above will be:

```
--frontier
Content-Type: text/plain

<JSON_START>
```

Other than Content-Type, it may contain the filename, encoding, etc.
Something to keep in mind the chunks may end wherever (could end in the middle of the frontier). 
The parsing could get quite tricky; I would search for the boundary key (frontier), and then check if the JSON starts after that. There would be two cases:

1. chunk: `<SOME_DATA> --frontier <FILE METADATA> <FILE_DATA>`
2. chunk 1: `<SOME_DATA> --fron`
   chunk 2: `ier <FILE METADATA> <FILE_DATA>`

Hope this helps!