# Storing Image Using Cloud Functions for Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to refactor some code to use Cloud Functions for Firebase. The code should store an image at a path in Firebase storage. For the most part the code is the exact same as before except now instead of

```
server.post('/', (req, res) => {
  // Some code 
}
```

I'm using the following according to the Firebase documentation

```
exports.getProcessedImage = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
  // Some code
});
```

The code worked previously but now I'm having trouble getting my test image to save to Firebase. Not sure why. I check the Network tab in developer tools and the getProcessedImage endpoint is triggering the code to run and it responds with a 200 code so not sure what the issue is. Thanks in advance for any help!

My full code is below :)

```js
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const request = require('request');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');

// Firebase Project ID and Service Account Key.
const gcs = storage({
  projectId: 'snapshelf-aabb55',
  keyFilename: './serviceAccountKey.json'
});

const bucket = gcs.bucket('snapshelf-aabb55.appspot.com');

function saveImage(url) {

    // Generate a random HEX string using crypto (a native node module).
    const randomFileName = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');

    // Fetch image info using a HTTP HEAD request.
    // https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/HEAD
    request.head(url, (error, info) => {
        if (error) {
            return console.error(error);
    }

    // Download image from Pixelz, then save the image to Firebase
    // using the Google Cloud API and the magic of Node Streams.
    // https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/#/docs/google-
    cloud/v0.52.0/storage/file
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28355079/how-do-node-js-streams-work
    request(url)
        .pipe(
            bucket.file(`sample/images/${randomFileName}`).createWriteStream({
                metadata: {
                    contentType: info.headers['content-type']
                }
            })
        )
        .on('error', (err) => {

            // Do something if the upload fails.
            console.error(err);
        })
        .on('finish', () => {

            // Do something when everything is done.

            // Get download url for stored image
            console.log('Image successfully uploaded to Firebase Storage!')
        });
    });
}

exports.getProcessedImage = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
    console.log(req.body.processedImageURL);
    /*
    if (req.body && req.body.processedImageURL) {

        // Get image from Pixelz and save it to Firebase Storage.
        saveImage(req.body.processedImageURL);

        return res.status(200).end();
    }

    res.status(400).end();
    */

    const url = 'https://www2.chemistry.msu.edu/courses/cem352/SS2017_Wulff/MichiganState.jpg'
    console.log(url);
    saveImage(url);
    console.log('Saving url');
    res.status(200).send();
});
```

Comment: Hi @maxwellgover, thank you for the question! I followed a very similar approach and did get it to work, maybe because I am using the Blaze plan like mentioned below. However... even though the image is saved on Firebase Storage Cloud, with the correct image header and total Kb... somehow the image doesn't open inside the firebase console dashboard... it is almost if the file is corrupted or saved using the wrong method or something. When I navigate to the img inside my bucket console, the image thumbnail keeps showing a spinner. Any ideas what this could be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you deploying your Function on Firebase with Spark Plan (Free)?

If the answer is yes, your problem is because of this:

> Firebase projects on the Spark plan can make only outbound requests to Google APIs. Requests to third-party APIs fail with an error. For more information about upgrading your project.

Since you are trying to make an *external request*, nothing is happening when your Function is executed :(

Comment: Is this rule changed? I can't find it in current Pricing Plans.

Comment: @FabioMarzocca, no, it hasn't changed. Just take a look the message that appears when you click **?** icon next to a service: it says "The Spark plan allows outbound network requests only to Google-owned services (...)".

Answer (score 0):

Thats easy right now! Since you have admin. just change

```
const bucket = gcs.bucket('snapshelf-aabb55.appspot.com');
```

to

```
const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();
```