# database triggers firebase function to download images from URL and save it to storage

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, google-cloud-functions

I want to download the image and save it to storage when my database is updated with the 'photo_url' field

```
exports.saveToStorage = functions.database.ref(`/images/${itemImageRef}`)
.onWrite(event => {
  const filePath = event.data.val();
  const filename = filePath.split('/').pop();

  var download = request.get(filePath).on('error', (err) => {
    console.log(err)
  })
  .pipe(fs.createWriteStream(filename));

  download.on('finish', () => {
    const bucket = gcs.bucket('id.appspot.com');
    const storagePath = `images/${filename}`;

    return bucket.upload(download, { destination: storagePath })
    .then(() => {
      console.log('success upload');
    });
  });
});
```

it logs "Error: EROFS: read-only file system, open 'image.jpg' at Error (native)." I suppose I cannot retrieve the file saved by createWriteStream?
So how should I download images from the web?

Comment: Maybe this would help you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43698405/3366109

Comment: thanks, but I've upgraded my plan so it should be able to make an external request.

Comment: @Jobsamuel, I've overlooked the solution, the code helps, I can now pipe the data to Firebase storage, which skips the step to store file 'locally' with fs in my original approach. The Firebase functions now able to save the file to storage, yet, it still doesn't recognize it's an image. Maybe I have to change the setting in metadata contentType.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

with the post suggested by @Jobsamuel, the code now works:

```
exports.saveToStorage = functions.database.ref(`/images/${itemImageRef}`)
.onWrite(event => {

  const filePath = event.data.val();
  const filename = filePath.split('/').pop();

  const bucket = gcs.bucket('id.appspot.com');
  const remoteWriteStream = bucket.file(filename).createWriteStream({
    metadata: { contentType: 'image/jpeg' }
  });

  request(filePath).pipe(remoteWriteStream)
  .on('error', (err) => console.log(err))
  .on('finish', () => console.log('success save image'));

});
```

By pipe the request result directly to the bucket, it solves the problem by skipping the step writing to a local file, which I suspect is the reason my original code fails. Also, don't forget to set contentType for images.